# Should questions recommending grooming implements be on topic and how specific?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

There is comments under these whether it is on topic and another, commenting that they are related.

[What is the most effective brush for knots in Bichon Frise fur?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/353/most-effective-brush-for-knots-for-a-bichon-frise)

[What kind of brush should be used with a Cavalier King Charles Spaniel?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-kind-of-brush-to-use-with-a-cavalier-king-charles-spaniel)

What does the community think?